# Window close button hijacking on Snow Leopard

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I'm working on an NSDocument-based app with multiple documents per window (tabs). This means I need to handle closing of windows myself so that I can review the documents belonging to the window before it's closed. In order to do this, I've accessed the NSWindow's close button using `standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton` and set the target/action of this button to my method instead of the standard (and private) `_close:` method.

This works great on Lion, but on Snow Leopard it causes issues. Whenever a modal dialog is displayed, the close button gets disabled as expected. But when the modal dialog is dismissed, on Snow Leopard the close button never gets reenabled. I've tried reenabling it programmatically afterwards using `[closeButton setEnabled:YES]` etc, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.  I've confirmed that this only happens when I've changed the target/action of the close button.

Any ideas on how to avoid this behavior on Snow Leopard, or maybe an alternative way of hijacking the close button? What is it that controls the enabled state of the toolbar buttons? Maybe I could override something there?

Comment: What happens if you remove the target and action before you present the dialog and add it when the dialog dismisses?

Comment: I thought I'd tried that, but now I did it and it looks like it works! Although it is a bit tricky find out exactly when to add and remove the target/action for all my different modal dialogs. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I would have thought you could use **windowShouldClose:** delegate method

Set the windows delegate to the AppDelegate. And in the AppDelegate use the windowShouldClose: delegate method to call your close method and to stop the window closing by returning **NO**.
In your method do all your checking and then performClose: the window. See my example

```
 NSWindow * thisWindow; //--pointer to window that will be closed
BOOL windowClose;//-- bool for confirming close of window.

- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender{
    thisWindow =sender;//-- set thisWindow to the sender window,the one that is to be closed )
    //if (sender ==theWindow) {//--you can use this to do further checking

        if (windowClose) {//-- Close window if YES
            return YES;  
        } 
    //}


    [self performSelector:@selector(myCloseWindow) ];//go to your method
    windowClose =FALSE;//-- reset
    return NO;//do not close window here
}

- (void) myCloseWindow {
    NSLog(@"closing window");//-- do your stuff
    windowClose =TRUE;//--give the ok to close the window
    [thisWindow performClose:thisWindow];//-- perform the close, which will be redirected back to the delegate, which will now allow the window to close
}
```

Comment: You would expect this to work, but it doesn't because this delegate method is called right before the window actually will be closed, which is not synonymous with the window close button in a document based app. For instance, if the document is unsaved, the document architecture tries to ask the user to save the document before it tries to close the window, so this delegate method would only be called after nagging the user, which is too late.